# How can I call dynamically a method that expects a LINQ expression with a dynamically generated LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have a bunch of entities related to others by a child-parent relationship. All those entities have a property that references to their parent, but its name is different depending on the entity. I have a method, called `Query` with the signature:

```cs
public virtual IQueryFluent<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
```

That method is in each of the repositories (repository pattern) that correspond to each of the instances. It's the way we recover instances from the DB.

I want to be able to recover a bunch of entities that have some specified parent by the value of their parent Id property. Let's say I have a method that's called like this:

```cs
masterTableService.GetParented("ChildEntityService", "ParentPropId", someParentIdValue);
```

So I created these two methods:

```cs
public MasterTableDto GetParented(string serviceName, string descriptionField, string parentField, int? parentId, string idField = ID_PROPNAME)
{
    var service = ResolveService(serviceName);
    var entityType = GetMethodAllReturnType(service);

    var parentProp = entityType.GetProperty(parentField);
    var parentPropType = parentProp.GetMethod.ReturnType;

    var x = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    var parentPropExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, parentField);
    var parentIdExpression = Expression.Constant(parentId);
    var parentIdSameTypeExpression = Expression.Convert(parentIdExpression, parentPropType);
    var body = Expression.Equal(parentPropExpression, parentIdSameTypeExpression);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, x);

    var parameters = new object[] { lambda };

    try
    {
        var foo = CallMethod(service, "Query", parameters);

        // More stuff...

        return dto;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public object CallMethod(object service, string methodName, object[] parameters)
{
    var serviceType = service.GetType();

    var method = serviceType.GetMethods().Where(mf => mf.GetParameters().Count() == 1).First();
    var result = method.Invoke(service, parameters); // Error :'(

    return result;
}
```

Everything works great until I reach the line marked with "Error". I get an exception:

```
Cannot convert 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Entities.SqlServer.RCE.Tramo,System.Boolean]]' to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

In fact, the `Query` method never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I created a console app using similar code and I can see 'Query' method is executed as expected. Here is the repo for  my console project: https://github.com/ruv1ru/InvokeDynamicMethod

Comment: @Ruviru You are right. I downloaded your code, tried it, and it works. I have no idea why it doesn't work when it's used to retrieve entities from the DB. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The code I wrote was correct, it turned out that I was picking another overload of the `Query` method with only one parameter. My bad...